How to increase VBA Do While loop efficiency?
I am trying to process a column in an excel sheet that contains around 50k rows. The column has text values that need to be evaluated and in case of a correct match, a part of that string needs to be extracted. The below code works well for 3000 rows but does not work beyond that.
Could someone please suggest an alternate to this code?
Function getManagerRating(EmpID As String)  
    row_number = 2  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  
    Application.EnableEvents = False  
    Do While row_number < 4000  
         cellValue = Sheets("Master").Range("AA" & row_number)  
         ID = Left$(cellValue, 8)  
         If ID = EmpID Then  
             If InStr(cellValue, "Overall Rating By Manager") > 0 Then  
             Position = Len(cellValue) - InStr(cellValue, "@")  
             reqValue = Right$(cellValue, Position)  
             End If  
         End If  
     row_number = row_number + 1  
    Loop  
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic  
    Application.EnableEvents = True  
    getManagerRating = reqValue  
End Function 


Read the values into an array  and loop over the array. I recommend to use Option Explict as well.

You might want to add some defensive code in case the InStr(cellValue, "@") fails.  You'll get entire cellvalue in that case.

My suggestion is to adjust the code like that
Function getManagerRating(EmpID As String)
    
    ' Adjust If you've got more rows
    ' or determine the number of filled rows
    Const NO_ROWS = 50000
    
    ' reading all cells into an arry
    ' it will be a 2D array
    Dim vdat As Variant
    vdat = Sheets("Master").Range("AA1:AA" & NO_ROWS)
           
    ' Declare all variable. That is good practise
    Dim i As Long, cellValue As Variant, ID As String, Position As Long, reqValue As String
    
    'Instead of a do loop one can use a for loop
    'using the lower and upper bound of the array
    For i = LBound(vdat) To UBound(vdat)
        'cellValue = Sheets("Master").Range("AA" & row_number)
        cellValue = vdat(i, 1)
        ID = Left$(cellValue, 8)
        If ID = EmpID Then
            If InStr(cellValue, "Overall Rating By Manager") > 0 Then
                Position = Len(cellValue) - InStr(cellValue, "@")
                reqValue = Right$(cellValue, Position)
                ' It seems that EmpID is unique
                ' i.e. you can leave the loop here
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    getManagerRating = reqValue
End Function

As the function only reads data from the worksheet once there is no need to turn off or change ScreenUpdating, Calculation Or Events

Thank you so much for the quick response Storax. This code is working great. However, I am facing an issue- there are multiple rows with the value "Overall Rating By Manager" corresponding to a single value for EmpID hence only the first entry is getting read. I need the latest entry against "Overall Rating By manager" to be captured, so I removed the Exit For statement. Doing so doesn't return the expected value. Any recommendation for the same?

You could loop backwards with For i = UBound(vdat) To LBound(vdat) Step -1 and keep the Exit For.  The issue is verly likley based on the data as you seem to have multiple entries with EmpID.

The backward loop is not returning the required value. The report records multiple values for each EmpID, however let me recheck the data.
